# Emails sent in django appear quoted in mail client

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi all I'm using django-registration to send and activation email when the user tries to sign up for the website. The code works fine but when I receive the email the text is shown as quoted as if it was forwarded. This can be seen in the screen shot below:

[image: How the activation appears in mail client]

Below is the template txt file that Django-Registration uses to send this email.
When I use the original text supplied by Django-Registration, it appears well in my email. I have edited to display my own custom message while preserving all appropriate tags:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% blocktrans with first_name=user.first_name%}
Dear {{ first_name }},

Welcome to the ***** ****** community. We look forward to matching you to                           
creative projects and great teams.

Please click the below link within {{ expiration_days }} days to validate   
your email. After this you can log in any time you wish.
{% endblocktrans %}

http://{{site.domain}}{% url 'registration_activate' activation_key %}

{% blocktrans %}
Best wishes,

***** and ******
***** ******
{% endblocktrans %}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and have been adjusting the formatting all afternoon but cannot work it out.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting is probably your mail client / webmail site quoting sections that are repeated from previous emails. If you view the original source of the received email, it should not be quoted.

Similarly, when you send the email to a new user for the first time, it should not appear as quoted.

Comment: Holy crap! Explains why putting original text back and trying worked, it's because it was different.I just deleted all past sent emails from inbox and trash a retried and it sent well formatted. I didn't know mail clients did this. I wasted an entire afternoon on this. Grrrr Thanks so much @Alasdair for your help!